# Upload Excel xls, Parse to Json, Edit Json output pdf or excel xls Nodejs Multer AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, excel

I am pretty new to NodeJs AngularJS and I am trying to learn by doing.

I am studying Programming and I need to do a project, in Angular Front End, that uploads an excel xls file to server, Node, and use some library, I found some, but dont understand how to use it example:node-xls-json

Then I need to edit in my frontend that json object in order to update, I think after the module do the magic y can consume that json in my angular front edit, and send updated json to node to convert it again to excel or pdf.

Do you thinks it is too hard to acomplish this? If you can please be clear for me to understand, remember I am new to all this.

Thanks in advance.

Andres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question, because being new to NodeJS and Angular doesn't really speak volumes about your skill level. It's definitely possible to do what you want to do, but it would likely take a while to do it. I had to do a similar project recently. I've been developing MEAN apps for about 6 months now, and I got stuck on a million different things. The best advice I can give is to be as modular as possible. I'd break things up like so:

1. Get your file read working. Do you need to save the file to your DB? If you're using MongoDB you'll need to learn to use GridFS to do so. If not, just read the file.
2. Parse the file. There are tons of packages that specifically read through excel files, but you'll need to do so extracting only the data you need. You might need to fool around with Regex to do this, which will be a pain.
3. Test your output.
4. Edit your output. These two should be pretty easy.
5. Write to file. Again, a lot of packages say they do this. I don't know which are good or not. [Node-workbook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_workbook) sounds promising, but I haven't used it.

Sorry to not give you a specific answer here. For a beginner programmer it'll be a lot of work, and it might be for an advanced one too. Good luck with it either way!

EDIT: I just found this link that might be helpful for you in explaining the different approaches employed by various Excel parsing packages: http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/

Comment: Thanks Joshua for your response!! Cheers!!

Comment: Just a quick update, but I found this super helpful as well. It also helps you learn D3's data functions and lodash. It's not vanilla JS, but it does make your life a whole lot easier when it comes to parsing: http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html